# Pandas Moving dates that are on the weekend to the next monday

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date

I have a pandas data frame with a column that has dates like so:

```
     Start
0    2020-08-01
1    2021-02-01
2    2021-02-01
3    2021-02-06
4    2020-12-01
```

How can i move the dates which are on a weekend to the next monday? Like so:

```
     Start
0    2020-08-03
1    2021-02-01
2    2021-02-01
3    2021-02-08
4    2020-12-01
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`pd.offsets.BusinessDay`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.tseries.offsets.BusinessDay.html#pandas.tseries.offsets.BusinessDay):

```
df["Start"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Start"])

print (df["Start"]+pd.offsets.BusinessDay(0))

0   2020-08-03
1   2021-02-01
2   2021-02-01
3   2021-02-08
4   2020-12-01
Name: Start, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```